# How to add multiple entities to send a communication message?

Tags: usability, gui-design, interaction-design

I'm designing an input component for selecting multiple entities (E.g. User and User groups) to send a communication message from administration page.

[image: UI for selecting recipients]

From my perspective UI-1 might create a visual load once user adds the recipients and it might also confuse the users that the selected values are from either one of the category. For the other UI-2 it might have interaction costs.

Which of the following can be efficient and effective? or Is there any better way of doing it?

*Note: I don't have the luxury of taking the design for the A/B testing. That is why reaching out for suggestions. Gmail like "to" address field design is not being considered because of technical limitation.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/127374/how-to-organise-a-multi-select-list-that-allows-for-selection-of-both-users-and

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But, this is much simpler. Users can select a user and also a group. Even if there is duplication of a user, the system will ignore it before sending. The concern here is that both the design has the sectional approach (as one of the answers) but which one of the above two will be better?

Comment: why do the two groups have to be seperate lists?

Comment: @timhuman The "User" option lets the admin select individual people by name and the "User groups" for selecting a Group name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be as simple as moving the +Add link outside of the input field in UI-2 to improve the usability of this feature.

Usually you want the input field to contain the input values, rather than treating them like 'filters' or 'tags' as UI-1 seems to suggest (and is often the standard design pattern these days).

Then you want the call-to-action or primary action to be clear, so moving it outside of the input field and perhaps making it into a button instead of a link could make the action easier to understand.

Not sure if the User and User Group fields contain aliases or actual email addresses, because you probably don't need to distinguish between them in that case, and it reduces the complexity of the input field further.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The fields contains only aliases